# Validação de formulário e localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, localstorage

Boa noite.
Estou a dois dias tentando fazer a validação de um form que vai salvar os dados do cadastro udo usuario no localstorage do navegador.
Recebi parte do código pronto, o problema é que o formulario salva os dados vazios, assim qualquer um pode entrar apenas clicando n botão registro e depois no botão de login.
Tentei usar um "if" para detectar quando os elementos estão vazios e exibir um alerta, mas ele exibe e impede que os dados sejam salvos mesmo quando os campos estão cheios. To desesperado com isso. Alguém me ajuda?
Fico extremamente grato a todos!

```js
var operacao = "A"; //"A"=Adição; "E"=Edição
var indice_selecionado = -1; //Índice do item selecionado na lista
var tbUsuarios;
$(function () {
tbUsuarios = localStorage.getItem("tbUsuarios");// Recupera os dados armazenados
tbUsuarios = JSON.parse(tbUsuarios); // Converte string para objeto
if (tbUsuarios == null) // Caso não haja conteúdo, iniciamos um vetor vazio
tbUsuarios = [];
});

function Adicionar() {
var usuario = JSON.stringify({
Nome: $("#txtNome").val(),
email: $("#txtEmail").val(),
Senha: $("#txtSenha").val()
});
if ($('#txtNome').is(':empty') || $('#txtEmail').is(':empty') || $('#txtSenha').is(':empty')){
alert('Preencha os campos vazios');
}
else{
tbUsuarios.push(usuario);
localStorage.setItem("tbUsuarios", JSON.stringify(tbUsuarios));
alert("Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!");
return true;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formRegister" id="formRegister" class="positionFormRegister">
<!--nome de usuario-->
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"></span>
<label></label>
<input name="txtName" id="txtNome" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Crie seu nome de Usuário" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<!--email-->
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"></span>
<label></label>
<input name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu endereço de e-mail" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<!--senha-->
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"></span>
<label></label>
<input name="txtSenha" id="txtSenha" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Crie sua senha" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<!--botão submit-->
<div>
<input id="buttonSubmitRegister" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg positionFormRegister" value="Cadastrar no e-Pro »" onclick="Adicionar()">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite cara, seu problema esta no 
`is(':empty')`
faz as condições com `$("#txtNome").val().length == 0`... isso para o email e senha também, eu testei e passou

Comment: Perfeito!!!!   Muito obrigado mesmo, funcionou direitinho. Agora vou fazer alertas personalizados com modais para cada campo.  Obrigado!!!